# read_attribute_before_type_cast don't seem to work with serialize:

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following model in my Rails app that uses serialization with JSON codec. My database columns are of the type 'text'

```
class Sample < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :face_detect, JSON
end
```

When I run the following in the rails console

```
Sample.first.read_attribute_before_type_cast('face_detect').class
```

I'm expecting a 'String' class, since I expect 'before_type_cast', also means before serialisation, but instead I get the 'Hash' class. How is this possible?

*(using rvm, with ruby-1.9.2-p290 with rails (3.1.3) and postgresql on Mac OSX)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serialization happens very deeply inside Arel, but I could access the pre-serialized value like this:

```
@sample.instance_variable_get("@attributes")["face_detect"].serialized_value
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Rails 4. Attributes values in `@attributes` are already deserialized from DB.

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 4:

```
@attributes['data'].serialized_value
```